# Is it possible to get the last element of the array and push it into an other array ( undo - redo)?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying implement and undo-redo function for a real-time application and I want to push an element to an array. This element is the last element in an other array. I want to achieve this in only one query to avoid concurrency problems.

I have a schema which has two arrays:

undoActions:[ActionSchema],

redoActions:[ActionSchema],

I tried this:

```
const result = await this.findOneAndUpdate({
      _id: id
    }, {
        $push: {
          redoActions: {
             $pop: {
                undoActions: 1
            },
          }
        }
      });
```

This doesn't do the pop in the undoActions and inserts and empty object in the redoActions array.

So when an undo function is performed I want to save the last element of the undoActions to redoActions.

Comment: You need to use transactions. $pop doesn't "return" the last element like javascript's Array.pop does. It just removes the element. $push on the other hand requires a value to push. It should be a value sent from the application not a reference to the other fields in the document. Even though you can use $push and $pop in the same update operation, you need to read the document first which leaves room for race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You could perform some simple `push()` and `splice()` (or `pop()`) on the arrays embedded in your object.

```
const actionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({}, {strict: false});
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  undoActions:[actionSchema]
  redoActions:[actionSchema]
});

User.findById(userId)
     .exec()
     .then(user => {
       user.redoActions.push(user.undoActions[user.undoActions.length-1])
       user.undoActions.splice(user.undoActions.length-1, 1)
       // or use user.undoActions.pop()
       return user.save();
    })
    .then(user => console.log(user))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```